# Storm Topology Builder with Akka Actors

Tags: java, akka, apache-storm

Following code, builds a topology starting with a spout. In this, `TenderEventSpout2` is an Akka Actor.

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("EventSpout", new TenderEventSpout2(), 1);
```

TenderEventSpout2 looks like this:

```
public class TenderEventSpout2 extends UntypedActor implements IRichSpout{  

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Object message){// throws IOException {}

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {}

    @Override
    public void open(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, SpoutOutputCollector spoutOutputCollector) {}

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {}


    //Override all the interface methods
    @Override
    public void close() {}

    public boolean isDistributed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void activate() {}

    @Override 
    public void deactivate() {}

    @Override
    public void ack(Object msgId) {}

    @Override
    public void fail(Object msgId) {}

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This compiles successfully, but I get this error:

> You cannot create an instance of [org.quadrisk.toplogy.TenderEventSpout2] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.

But creating an actor using actorOf as suggested would return me an object of ActorRef type. How do I go about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure.. Did you try a simple cast? If a cast does no work, you can use two classes instead of one, and add an `ActorRef` member variable into you spout class.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Simple cast didn't work. So followed your second suggestion. It works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use use two classes instead of one:

1. the first implements `Actor`
2. the second implements `IRichSpout`

In your spout, you add an `ActorRef` member variable, that hold an instance of your first class that you get via `ActorSystem#actorOf(...)`.

Comment: Your answer is quite confusing. Creating two classes is correct approach, but one of them is for spout and the another one is an `Actor`. Actor proxy `ActorRef` should be created within the spout class, that would act as a handle to ActorWorld. This way, there would be no problem in involving `Akka Actor` within or with spout.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. My bad -- I put this answer to quickly without rethinking it. Update it now. (Have to confess, that I am not an Akka expert)

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for your help. I'm marking it as the Answer now.

Comment: Seems you are not completely happy with my answer -- in your comment above (ie, question), you said "It works." -- Please correct my, if some parts of my answer are not good.